# Simple "pager" directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

I've created some simple pager:

index.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="NewsCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="news in newsList">
        <li ng-show="$index < count">{{ news }}</li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="more()" ng-hide="count > newsList.length">More</button>
</div>
```

newsCtrl.coffee:

```
angular.module('yoApp').controller 'NewsCtrl', ($scope) ->
    $scope.count = 5
    $scope.newsList = [
        1
        2
        3
        4
        5
        6
        7
        8
        9
    ]
    $scope.more = -> $scope.count += 5
```

Its purpose is to initially display certain amount of some entries (in this case news), after I click "more" to show 5 more, after I click "more" again 5 more and when all are visible to hide "more" button. However I want this logic to be reusable across my site and possibly super easy to implement.

I want it to look something like:

```
<ul pager="news in newsList">
    <li>{{ news }}</li>
</ul>
```

or something similar. The button (transculsion?) and all the logic should be handed automatically by directive.

Comment: it musts necessairly be a list of elements? what about a tab?

Comment: I would check out this example. It is not a directive, but is a better way of paging. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/)

Comment: @ZackArgyle Argyle, But that's not what I want to achieve. :) I want pagination to work exactly as I described, it's a business requirement.

Comment: Oh I understand, I was referring to the ng-show portion. All of those elements are still rendered so it will be slow. The way in the fiddle shows how to use filters, which will render much faster.